# Order array of objects by date then by string value if dates are the same

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I have an array of objects:

```
arr = [
        {
            name : 'Gary',
            DOB : '01/01/1980',
            importance: 'High'
        },
        {
            name : 'Bill',
            DOB : '01/01/1985',
            importance: 'High'
        },
        {
            name : 'Joe',
            DOB : '01/01/1981',
            importance: 'Medium'
        },
        {
            name : 'Phillip',
            DOB : '01/01/1981',
            importance: 'High'
        },
        {
            name : 'Ed',
            DOB : '01/01/1980',
            importance: 'Low'
        },
        {
            name : 'Nix',
            DOB : '01/01/1980',
            importance: 'High'
        },
        {
            name : 'Pat',
            DOB : '01/01/1980',
            importance: 'Low'
        }
    ]
```

I'm sorting these guys by two fields, first by `DOB`, and if they have the same DOB, then by `importance`, Low to High, so Low at the top and High at the bottom.

I can compare their dates easily enough, but I'm having a hard time ordering them by their importance after that?

Can anyone offer any advice?

```
var importanceOrder = ['Low', 'Normal', 'High'];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.dueDate.value != b.dueDate.value){
        return a.dueDate.value < b.dueDate.value ? -1 : 1;
    } else {
    //??
    }
});
```

Comment: `Low`, `Normal` and `High` should be comparable somehow to sort. Try to map them to integers and then sort by the interger, which will make it easier.

Comment: OK, if you have this `var importanceOrder = ['Low', 'Normal', 'High'];`, and you have, say, a variable ``a = "Low"` then another that `b = "High"`. With this information alone, how would you check if `a > b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object for the sortorder of `imortance` and a function for getting an ISO date.

```js
const getISO = s => s.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$3-$1-$2');

var array = [{ name: 'Gary', DOB: '01/01/1980', importance: 'High' }, { name: 'Bill', DOB: '01/01/1985', importance: 'High' }, { name: 'Joe', DOB: '01/01/1981', importance: 'Medium' }, { name: 'Phillip', DOB: '01/01/1981', importance: 'High' }, { name: 'Ed', DOB: '01/01/1980', importance: 'Low' }, { name: 'Nix', DOB: '01/01/1980', importance: 'High' }, { name: 'Pat', DOB: '01/01/1980', importance: 'Low' }],
    order = { Low: 1, Normal: 2, High: 3 };


array.sort((a, b) => getISO(a.DOB).localeCompare(getISO(b.DOB)) || order[a.importance] - order[b.importance]);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, this is pretty straightforward, firstly check whether dates are different and sort them in that manner and then if they are equal (`x - x == 0` which will return false in first equation) check their importance, easy as that :)

`arr.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.DOB) - new Date(b.DOB) || importanceOrder.indexOf(a.importance) - importanceOrder.indexOf(b.importance))`

Comment: `new Date(a.DOB)` -- this doesn't return what you expect. Try it on console. The bahaviour is not consistent among the browsers.

Comment: @31piy couldn't assume what the format is, because OP posted all dates with `01/01`, so it returns exactly what I expected, I just picked American date notation with "month-day-year" order

Comment: You're not the only one who gets confused at it, mate. :)